# Cant get past - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: ios, swift

I know this topic has been discussed before. Im beginner so I tried my best but couldn't get past the error. I am following youtube tutorial on making an app to use iOS camera. I believe they used swift 3 and older iOS so Im guessing that's the issue here. I took their source code and still got same error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEhRk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmbKp.png)

Answer (score 0):

`currentCamera` appears to be `nil` and you are trying to force-unwrap it. This might be why you have a crash. I would try to understand why that local variable is `nil` and not the value you think that it is, before you try force-unwrapping it.

If "force unwrapping" is foreign to you, I'd read up on the some of the [basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) of how Optionals work in Swift. There is a lot of content out there on how to deal with Optionals values.